# how to capture pexpect sendline command output and redirect it to logfile?

Tags: python, pexpect, logfile

When i run the below command manually in shell

```
[root@Rhel67GA-Valencia ~]# /DPDK2/testpmd -c 3 -n 3 -d /DPDK2/librte_pmd_oce.so -w 0000:01:00.00 -w 0000:01:00.01 -- -i --nb-cores=1 --nb-ports=2
```

i get the below output on terminal:

```
COMMAND OUTPUT Beginning:

Port 0: 00:90:FA:30:97:26
Configuring Port 1 (socket 0)
librte_pmd_oce:
oce_pf_dev_rx_start hw_vlan_strip = 0x1

Port 1: 00:90:FA:30:97:2A
Checking link statuses...
Port 0 Link Up - speed 10000 Mbps - full-duplex
Port 1 Link Up - speed 10000 Mbps - full-duplex
Done

testpmd> start             <=== USER INPUT ===>
io packet forwarding - CRC stripping disabled - packets/burst=32
nb forwarding cores=1 - nb forwarding ports=2
RX queues=1 - RX desc=128 - RX free threshold=0
RX threshold registers: pthresh=0 hthresh=0 wthresh=0
TX queues=1 - TX desc=512 - TX free threshold=0
TX threshold registers: pthresh=0 hthresh=0 wthresh=0
TX RS bit threshold=0 - TXQ flags=0x0

testpmd> stop                <=== USER INPUT ===>
Telling cores to stop...
Waiting for lcores to finish...

---------------------- Forward statistics for port 0  ----------------------
RX-packets: 24             RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 24
TX-packets: 24             TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 24
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------- Forward statistics for port 1  ----------------------
RX-packets: 24             RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 24
TX-packets: 24             TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 24
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

+++++++++++++++ Accumulated forward statistics for all ports+++++++++++++++
RX-packets: 48             RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 48
TX-packets: 48             TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 48  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Done.

testpmd> quit                  <=== USER INPUT ===>
Stopping port 0...done
Stopping port 1...done
bye...
[root@Rhel67GA-Valencia ~]#

End of COMMAND OUTPUT
```

When i try to run the same command in python script using pexpect module i dont see any output on the terminal, but the command is executed successfully.

I need to capture the above COMMAND OUTPUT to a logfile.

below is script i am using

```
sample.py:

cmd = "/DPDK2/testpmd -c 3 -n 3 -d /DPDK2/librte_pmd_oce.so -w 0000:01:00.00     -w 0000:01:00.01 -- -i --nb-cores=1 --nb-ports=2"

child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)


child.expect("testpmd>")


child.sendline('start')

print "\ntestpmd> start \n"

time.sleep(30)


child.sendline('stop')

print "\ntestpmd> stop \n"


child.sendline('quit')

time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Tried using:     child.logfile = open("/home/dpdk.log", "w") in the script, but the sendline output is not getting redirected to dpdk.log file

Comment: Before `child.sendline('stop')` and `child.sendline('quit')` there should be `child.expect("testpmd>")`.

Comment: Did that fix the problem?

Comment: Yes. I see the output getting redirected to logfile. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Call `child.expect` before each call to `child.sendline`:

```
child.expect("testpmd>")
child.sendline('start')

child.expect("testpmd>")
child.sendline('stop')

child.expect("testpmd>")
child.sendline('quit')

child.interact()
```